# BigQuery SQL: How to use different columns in CASE expression

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Input Data:

```
columnA  columnB
true     false
true     true
false    false
false    true
```

Problem Statement:
From above mentioned data, I want to use different columns to get the result.

Expected Output:

```
columnA  columnB   result
true     false     A
true     true      B
false    false     C
false    true      C
```

Tried SQL Query:

```
SELECT
columnA, 
columnB,
CASE columnA WHEN 'true' AND columnB ='false' THEN 'A'
             WHEN 'true' AND columnB ='true' THEN 'B'
             ELSE 'C' END AS result
```

It seems unable to use different columns in CASE expression. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use different columns but, you need to rewrite your query

```
SELECT
columnA, 
columnB,
CASE WHEN columnA  = 'true' AND columnB ='false' THEN 'A'
             WHEN columnA  = 'true' AND columnB ='true' THEN 'B'
             ELSE 'C' END AS result
FROM mytable
```

Comment: If `columnA` and `columnB` store boolean values, then you may drop the single quotes around `'true'`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below "version"

```
select *,
  case (columnA, columnB) 
    when (true, false) then 'A'
    when (true, true) then 'B'
    else 'C'
  end result
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]